# Wordpress : Call wp_create_user function from external?

Tags: wordpress, api, function, curl, user-registration

In Wordpress, i want to create New Users from external. I've found this is function in wordpress:

```
wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
```

So how can i run this function from external call please?

I mean, how to run this function from either:

- Via simple URL with GET, like: `www.example.com/adduser/?username=james&password=simpletext&email=myemail`
- Via cURL with POST

.. from external website.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this but also make sure that the listening url has a handler to handle the request in your `WordPress` end (using `GET` methof)

```
function curlAdduser($strUrl)
{
    if( empty($strUrl) )
    {
        return 'Error: invalid Url given';
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $return;
}
```

Call the function from external site :

```
curlAdduser("www.example.com/adduser?username=james&password=simpletext&email=myemail");
```

**Update :** using `POST` method

```
function curlAdduser($strUrl, $data) {
    $fields = '';
    foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
        $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
    }
    $fields = rtrim($fields, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strUrl);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $return;
}
```

Call the function with `data`

```
$data = array(
    "username" => "james",
    "password" => "simpletext",
    "email" => "myemail"
);
curlAdduser("www.example.com/adduser", $data);
```

Comment: (Sorry for my dummyness) But where do i add the `function curlAdduser(){}` in the Wordpress please? In `functions.php`? Then the WP will straight-away give me that `/adduser` RestFUL URL for me, simply?

Comment: Yes, you can add this function in your `functions.php` file and then use it from anywhere.

Comment: Hi, i put it but that still doesn't mean i have `/adduser` specif path. I mean, e.g, for the `GET` method, i can even call from home page directly, like: `www.example.com?username=X&password=X&email=X`. And the function got triggered. But I want it working ONLY for `www.example.com/adduser` path, entry point.

Comment: Don't you have that path to the external site ?