# Login to WordPress via curl from Magento

Tags: php, wordpress

I am sending curl `post` request to WordPress website from Magento website and trying to login user in WordPress by using `wp_set_auth_cookie` and `wp_set_current_user` functions. But I cannot get the user logged in.
I am using following code to send CURL request from Magento:

```
 $response = send_curl_request('http://my.wordpress.website', http_build_query( array( 'data' => 'some data' ) ));
var_dump($response); 
// printing NULL
function send_curl_request($url){
            $curl_handle = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
            curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); 
            curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
            curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
            if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && (ini_get('safe_mode') == 'Off' or !ini_get('safe_mode'))) {
              curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
              curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            }else {
                curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
                $url = curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
                curl_close($curl_handle);
                $curl_handle = curl_init(); 
                $url = str_replace('?','/?',$url); 
                curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
                curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            }
            $response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
            $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if(in_array($httpCode, array(400, 401, 403, 404, 500, 503)) && $httpCode != 200){
                // service connection timeout;
            }else{
                if(curl_errno($curl_handle) == 28){
                    // timeout;
                }
            }
            curl_close($curl_handle);
 return $response;
}
```

In WordPress website, I am using following code to respond to CURL request (in `functions.php` file):

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'func' );
function func(){
    die('at wordpress');
            // check for data sent via curl
    if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
        wp_set_auth_cookie( 256, true );
            wp_set_current_user( 256 );
        print_r(array('status' => 'ok'));
        die('done');
    }
}
```

This is not even printing `at wordpress` that I am checking for debugging.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can anyone suggest the alternative way to achieve the desired result, if above is not gonna work?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131483/wordpress-call-wp-create-user-function-from-external/19133473#19133473), you may get an idea.